# URL prefix using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to prefix the incoming URL using an htaccess file. For example, the URL might be `http://localhost/george_shop.html`, I want the htaccess to prefix it like `http://localhost/route/george_shop.html`

This is my htaccess right now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Update**
If it helps, this is the Slim3 htaccess

Comment: @anubhava I need it as a workaround to make a website dynamic

Comment: You will need to provide more details in question. Do you want route before every existing file or every non-existing file?

Comment: @anubhava Its a slim application with twig as the template engine. These are not links to actual files, its just a route and the function that handles it will respond with the html. I changed the example for better clarity

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I suspect you should not be relying on mod_rewrite rules. Explore routing in `slim` framework/.

Comment: Unfortunately slim cant solve my problem, I just need to know how I can add a ***base*** to my url before the slim rewrite rules. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you  use slim regexp, your route can by dynamic by doing something like so:

```
$app->get('/{route:.*(?:html)$}', function($req, $res, $args) {});
```

Hope it helps